Карусель на Slick slider с гигантской картинкой в центре
Нужно сделать карусель с огромной картинкой по центру и маленькими по бокам как на схеме:

Решил использовать Slick slider. У Slick есть соответствующий конфиг centerMode: true, который используется для похожих целей, есть достаточно много примеров использования. Центральная картинка увеличивается через CSS свойство: transform: scale();
Но... Максимальное значение scale(); которое можно поставить 1.5 при превышении этого порога и дальнейшем увеличении центральная картинка наезжает на соседние и в большом размере полностью их закрывает. Принудительное увеличение контейнера с центральной картинкой с помощью CSS свойства width приводит к тому, что центральное изображение уезжает в бок от центра - размеры и центрирование калькулируются скриптом Slick и заточены под единообразный размер изображений.
Как можно решить эту задачу c помощью Slick или посоветуйте другой скрипт галереи под эту задачу?


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slider').slick({
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '0px',
    nextArrow: '.project__next',
    slidesToShow: 5
  });
});
.slick-center img {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.slick-slide img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.slick-slide {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.slick-center {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.project__next img{
  width:50px;
  height:20px;
}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css" />

<div class="slider">      
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">

  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">

  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">

  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">

  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
<div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="project__next">
    <span>Next</span><img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/B/5/C/M/6/i/right-grey-arrow.svg">
  </div>




Почитайте тут https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

transform-origin не даст ничего в данном случае, не зависимо от точки относительно которой происходит трансформация внутри родительского контейнера, у родительского контейнера уже жестко задана ширина и центровка относительно соседних  слайдов.

Поправить? Не проблема. Вот только посмотрев на одну лишь кашу стилей по умолчанию хочется взять того пейсателя за причинное место (голову) и ударить чем-нибудь посильнее.
Но что имеем, то и правим? Поехали. Для начала полностью "убьём" подключённые  css, потому что бороться с ними бесполезно (огромное количество бессмысленного и устаревшего мусора, который !important-ом устанет рука перебивать) и напишем свои не нагружая ничем лишним (ну может капельку красоты.) Звучит может и жутко, но все куда проще.


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slider').slick({
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '0px',
    slidesToShow: 5
  });
});
.slider {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slick-list {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
.slick-slider .slick-track, .slick-slider .slick-list {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.slick-track {
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.slick-slide {
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
  justify-content: center;
}
.slider img {
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
  object-fit: cover;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}
.slick-center img {
  transform: scale(2.2);
  transition: all .5s;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <div>
    <img src="https://itproger.com/img/courses/x1476977488.jpg.pagespeed.ic.RdIpJiqNIr.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">

  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">

  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">

  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
</div>



P.S. к слову, куда проще этот свайпер переписать заново или воспользоваться чем-нибудь современным и проверенным, поскольку привести к виду как вы хотите вероятно всё равно не выйдет, ибо  javascript отвечающий за размер контейнера и его перерасчёт всё равно решает. Может что-то и есть в его опциях, но выяснять это уже нет интереса (уж больно он кривой).

Спасибо! А не дадите наводку что из современного можно взять за основу, не фреймворк, а готовый скрипт слайдера?  Писать с нуля не позволяет квалификация и временные рамки проекта.

@EvTr сожалею, но подсказать что-то готовое затрудняюсь, поскольку не сталкивался с вашей задачей. Однако, если вам нужно оттолкнуться от чего-то, то вот вам список соответствующий сегодняшним реалиям. Однако, думаю, вы там не найдёте готового решения, и так или иначе придётся править js ручками. Первое на что я бы обратил внимание так это на то, чтобы контейнеры считались %. А достаточно навороченный по дефалту и оптимально простой для правок, как мне кажется,  — TinySlider.
